# Android emulator - enable Multi-display under extended controls?

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, android-automotive

I downloaded and built the android emulator from the official repo, following https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/emu-master-dev#welcome-to-the-android-emulator

I am trying to get the option to add `multiple displays` to show up in the extended controls view.

`android/data/advancedFeatures.ini` -> has `MultiDisplay = on`
`android/data/advancedFeaturesCanary.ini` -> has `MultiDisplay = on`
`android/android-emu/android/avd/hardware-properties.ini` -> has values for `hw.display1.width`, `hw.display1.height`, `hw.display1.density`, as well as `hw.display1.xOffset` and `hw.display1.yOffset`.

**However**, there is no second display, nowhere to be seen or found.
I am trying to launch/mount the `system image` for the Android Car emulator. Which I have built from the sources as well.

Any tips on what I am actually missing?

I already know that, the Android Emulator for the Pixel system image comes with the multi-display support enabled, and it's available in the Canary Channel with Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do to Emulator settings, click on Display option and add secondary display.

Comment: I can't see it where is it?